# How do I escape all double quotes in a raw URL string?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm designing an app that will have a list of youtube videos in a table view. So I need to work with an 'embed' URL of a youtube video, like this one:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/La4HRfL5tV4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am trying to write a function that escapes all doublequotes inside the URL so that I can pass the 'clear' URL as a String to a Video class' attribute:

```
func backSlashRawLink(_ url: String) -> String {
    return url.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "\\\"")
}
```

The question is, how do I pass a String containing doubleqoutes as a parameter to this function?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean here. The data you're showing isn't an URL. It's HTML that includes an URL (but the URL doesn't have any double quotes in it). It's not clear what you mean by "a Video class' attribute" or what problem you're encountering. If you already have a String variable that contains double quotes, then you pass it as the first parameter of the function, just like if it didn't have double quotes in it.

Comment: You should consider using a HTML parser (like [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) or [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple). Or, if this were from XML, I'd just use `NSXMLParser`. These approaches get you out of the world of trying to handle all of the edge case scenarios entailed by XML/HTML and you don't have to worry about the quotes.

Comment: BTW, if you are HTML scraping, you might want to check the terms of service for that site, as this practice is generally frowned upon. If you use the official API, it also eliminates this sorts of parsing issues.